# Spark number of partitions logic for Join operator

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to understand how spark calculate number of partitions when joining data.
I am using spark 1.6.2 with yarn and Hadoop.

I have a code

```
val df1 = ..... 
val df2 =  .... .cache() //small cached dataframe
//cartesian join
val joined =  df1 join(broadcast(df2)) persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER) 

println(df1.rdd.partitions.size )  //prints 10
println(df2.rdd.partitions.size )  //prints 28
println(joined.rdd.partitions.size )  //prints 33
```

can someone explain why the result is 33 ?

**EDIT**

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [key1#6L,key2#9,key3#21L,temp_index#33L,CASE WHEN (key1_type#2 = business) THEN ((rand#179 * 2000.0) + 10000.0) ELSE ((rand#179 * 2000.0) + 5000.0) AS amount#180]
+- Project [key1_type#2,key1#6L,key2#9,key3#21L,temp_index#33L,randn(-5800712378829663042) AS rand#179]
   +- Join Inner, None
      :- InMemoryRelation [key1_type#2,key1#6L,key2#9,key3#21L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, false, 1), BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Inner, None, None
      +- BroadcastHint
         +- InMemoryRelation [temp_index#33L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), Project [id#32L AS temp_index#33L], None

== Physical Plan ==
Project [key1#6L,key2#9,key3#21L,temp_index#33L,CASE WHEN (key1_type#2 = business) THEN ((rand#179 * 2000.0) + 10000.0) ELSE ((rand#179 * 2000.0) + 5000.0) AS amount#180]
+- Project [key1_type#2,key1#6L,key2#9,key3#21L,temp_index#33L,randn(-5800712378829663042) AS rand#179]
   +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Inner, None
      :- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [key1_type#2,key1#6L,key2#9,key3#21L], InMemoryRelation [key1_type#2,key1#6L,key2#9,key3#21L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, false, 1), BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Inner, None, None
      +- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [temp_index#33L], InMemoryRelation [temp_index#33L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), Project [id#32L AS temp_index#33L], None
```

Comment: what is the value of `spark.default.parallelism`

Comment: the value of this parameter is 200